# Listview With Data Pager Control Sort Error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a listview that I bind using  custom code in the code behind. The listview has a datapager and needs to be sorted.

I created a custom sort routine that successfully sorts the list view. The issue is that if I change the page using the datapager, the sort is not maintained (i.e. page 2 and up are not sorted)

Here is the code for the list view:

```
 <asp:ListView ID="lv_positions_i_posted" runat="server" DataKeyNames="postingid" OnPagePropertiesChanging="lv_positions_i_posted_paging" OnItemDataBound="lv_positions_i_posted_ItemDataBound">
 <LayoutTemplate>
    <table id="Table2" runat="server">
        <tr id="Tr1" runat="server">
            <td id="Td1" runat="server">
                <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="1"
                style="border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2" style="background-color: darkseagreen;">Posting    </th>
                        <th colspan="1" style="background-color: sandybrown;">Applications    </th>
                        <th colspan="4">Positions I Posted    </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="Tr2" runat="server" style="color: #000000;">
                        <th id="Th1" runat="server" style="background-color: darkseagreen;">View    </th>
                        <th id="Th2" runat="server" style="background-color: darkseagreen;">Edit    </th>
                        <th id="Th3" runat="server" style="background-color: sandybrown;">View    </th>
                        <th id="Th4" runat="server">ID    </th>
                        <th id="Th6" runat="server">Title    </th>
                        <th id="Th8" runat="server">Posting Date
                             <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel3" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
                                 <ContentTemplate>
 <asp:ImageButton ID="SortPostingButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Up2.png" Height="20px" Width="20px" ToolTip="Sort" OnClick="PostingSort1_Click" /> 
                                 </ContentTemplate>
                                 <Triggers>
 <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="SortPostingButton" />
                                 </Triggers>
                             </asp:UpdatePanel>

                         </th>
                        <th id="Th9" runat="server">Status
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="SortStatusButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/Up2.png" Height="20px" Width="20px" ToolTip="Sort" OnClick="StatusSort1_Click" />
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="Tr3" runat="server">
            <td id="Td2" runat="server"
            style="text-align: center; background-color: #CCCCCC; font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color: #000000;">
                <asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lv_positions_i_posted" PageSize="20">
                    <Fields>
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="True"
                        ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                        <asp:NumericPagerField ButtonCount="10" />
                        <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowLastPageButton="True"
                        ShowNextPageButton="False" ShowPreviousPageButton="False" />
                    </Fields>
                </asp:DataPager>
            &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</LayoutTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr style="background-color: #DCDCDC; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ViewPostingButton" runat="server" ToolTip="View Posting" ImageUrl="~/images/green-eye-icon-new-small.png" Width="30px" Height="18.75px" OnCommand="ViewPostingButton_Click" CommandArgument='    <%#Eval("PostingID")%>' />

        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditPostingButton" runat="server" ToolTip="Edit Posting" ImageUrl="~/images/pencil_small.png" Width="18.75px" Height="18.75px" OnCommand="EditPostingButton_Click" CommandArgument='    <%#Eval("PostingID")%>' />

        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ViewPostingApplicantButton" runat="server" ToolTip="View Applicants" ImageUrl="~/images/green-eye-icon-new-small.png" Width="30px" Height="18.75px" ImageAlign="Middle" OnCommand="ViewPostingApplicantButton_Click" CommandArgument='    <%#Eval("PostingID")%>' />

        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:Label ID="PostingID" runat="server" Text='    <%# Eval("PostingID") %>' Visible="true" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="PostingTitle" runat="server" Text='    <%# Eval("PostingTitle") %>' Visible="true" ToolTip='    <%# Eval("PostingTitleFull") %>' />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:Label ID="PostingDate" runat="server" Text='    <%# Eval("PostingDate","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Visible="true" />
        </td>


        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:Label ID="PostingStatusID" runat="server" Text='    <%# Eval("PostingStatusID") %>' Visible="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
<AlternatingItemTemplate>
    <tr style="background-color: #FFF8DC; color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ViewPostingButton" runat="server" ToolTip="View Posting" ImageUrl="~/images/green-eye-icon-new-small.png" Width="30px" Height="18.75px" OnCommand="ViewPostingButton_Click" CommandArgument='    <%#Eval("PostingID")%>' />

        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="EditPostingButton" runat="server" ToolTip="Edit Posting" ImageUrl="~/images/pencil_small.png" Width="18.75px" Height="18.75px" OnCommand="EditPostingButton_Click" CommandArgument='    <%#Eval("PostingID")%>' />

        </td>

        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ViewPostingApplicantButton" ToolTip="View Applicants" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/green-eye-icon-new-small.png" Width="30px" Height="18.75px" ImageAlign="Middle" OnCommand="ViewPostingApplicantButton_Click" CommandArgument='    <%#Eval("PostingID")%>' />

        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:Label ID="PostingID" runat="server" Text='    <%# Eval("PostingID") %>' Visible="true" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="PostingTitle" runat="server" Text='    <%# Eval("PostingTitle") %>' Visible="true" ToolTip='    <%# Eval("PostingTitleFull") %>' />
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:Label ID="PostingDate" runat="server" Text='    <%# Eval("PostingDate","{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Visible="true" />
        </td>


        <td style="text-align: center">
            <asp:Label ID="PostingStatusID" runat="server" Text='    <%# Eval("PostingStatusID") %>' Visible="true" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</AlternatingItemTemplate>
<EmptyDataTemplate>
    <table id="Table1" runat="server"
    style="background-color: #FFFFFF; border-collapse: collapse; border-color: #999999; border-style: none; border-width: 1px;">
        <tr>
            <td>No data was returned.    </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Here is where I capture the sort:

```
protected void PostingSort1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    if (TheListView.Text == "1")
    {
        if (LastSortField.Text == "p.postingdate")
        {
            if (LastSortDirection.Text == "asc")
            {
                ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;
                button.ImageUrl = "~/images/Down2.png";
            }
            else
            {
                ImageButton button = (ImageButton)sender;
                button.ImageUrl = "~/images/Up2.png";
            }
        }
    }
    currentLV = TheListView.Text;
    BindListview(currentLV, "p.postingdate");

}
```

Here is where I bind/re-bind the listview:

```
protected void BindListview(string selectedItem, string orderby)
{
    string SQL = "";
    string direction = "";
        SQL = "Select  Statment Here";
        if (orderby != "")
        {
            if (selectedItem == TheListView.Text)
            {
                if (orderby == LastSortField.Text)
                {
                    if (LastSortDirection.Text == "asc")
                    {
                        direction = "desc";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        direction = "asc";
                    }
                    SQL += " Order by " + orderby + " " + direction;
                    LastSortDirection.Text = direction;
                    LastSortField.Text = orderby;
                }
                else
                {
                    SQL += " Order by " + orderby;
                    LastSortDirection.Text = "asc";
                    LastSortField.Text = orderby;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SQL += " Order by '" + orderby ;
                LastSortDirection.Text = "asc";
                LastSortField.Text = orderby;
            }
        }
        else
        {
                SQL += " Order by PostingID asc";
                LastSortDirection.Text = "asc";
                LastSortField.Text = "PostingID";
        }
        DataSet ds = jdh.GetDataSetFromDB(SQL);
        lv_positions_i_posted.DataSource = ds;
        lv_positions_i_posted.DataBind();
        lv_positions_i_posted.Visible = true;
        ds.Dispose();
    }
```

As I indicated, the displayed listview data is sorted correctly EXCEPT it is not being maintained when I use the datapager. I am expecting that the entire listview is sorted correctly throughout the paged data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I forgot that I captured the datapager page change and was not passing in the "orderby" variable. Once I fixed that it works correctly.

```
protected void lv_positions_i_manage_paging(object sender, PagePropertiesChangingEventArgs e)
{
    (lv_positions_i_manage.FindControl("DataPager1") as DataPager).SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
    if (LastSortDirection.Text == "asc")
    {
        LastSortDirection.Text = "desc";
    }
    else
    {
        LastSortDirection.Text = "asc";
    }

        BindListview("2", LastSortField.Text);
}
```